# Compile IE 11 add-on as MSI or EXE

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, internet-explorer, compilation

I have written an IE 11 plugin using Visual Studio 2017.
I know I can install the plugin via Visual Studio command prompt, but is there a way I can compile the plugin into and executable .exe or .msi file?

Any help or pointing in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Visual Studio has Setup Wizard project templates... File>New>Project>Templates>Other Project types>Visual Studio installer

Comment: @RobParsons thank you, but all this does is add the files into my programmes drive. How can I get it to actually install the IE add-on?